# Navigation Drawer is not opening from left for method drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

**My HomeScreen.java**

```
    public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
            private Toolbar toolbar;
            private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
            private NavigationView navigationView;
            private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.home_screen);

                instantiateViews();
toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        }

            public void instantiateViews(){

                    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.drawer_menu_toolbar);
                    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.home_screen_main_drawer_layout);
                    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.home_screen_navigation_view);

                }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
                Log.i("CLICKED","clicked");
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
            }


     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
```

**My Problem:**

On the initial click of the ActionBarToggle the navigation drawer isn't opening. It opens only when i have swiped right initially and after that, the ActionBarToggle and the Right Swipe both open the drawer. Only when the application is restarted, the click on ActionBarToggle doesn't work. So i tried to register the click of the ActionBarToggle and in the logs, whenever i click it, it displays the following

**Log.i**

```
2019-06-21 10:00:11.860 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
2019-06-21 10:00:13.282 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/chatty: uid=10184(com.example.gofresh) identical 2 lines
2019-06-21 10:00:14.201 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
2019-06-21 10:00:15.031 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
2019-06-21 10:00:15.830 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
2019-06-21 10:00:16.383 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
2019-06-21 10:00:17.920 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/chatty: uid=10184(com.example.gofresh) identical 2 lines
2019-06-21 10:00:18.497 7467-7467/com.example.gofresh I/CLICKED: clicked
```

What code should i put in onOptionsItemSelected() so that the ActionBarToggle even responds to the first click?

**My home_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Top Layout-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="@color/blue">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchHere"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"
                    android:hint="Search Here"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/home_screen_menu_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/home_screen_menu_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Add XML use for this activity

Comment: I have edited the post and added it. Please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think you are missing visibility because you set Navigation-view.
**android:visibility="gone"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_screen_main_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeScreen">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Top Layout-->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/drawer_menu_fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/search_toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@android:"


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/searchHere"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/seachbar_homescreen"
                    android:hint="Search Here"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/home_screen_navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/home_screen_menu_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/home_screen_menu_drawer" />
-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/home_screen_menu_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/home_screen_menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Handle visibility in code runtime before toggle issue

Comment: I have been literally thinking my way around what have i done wrong for 2 days now. The visibility thing , i did was actually temporary, i wanted to check something but as it turns out, i completely forgot about it. Thank you so much

Comment: Ohh man. You saved my day!!!